# Cycle does not show all the results as it shows in the SQL

Tags: php, sql-server

my code is not showing all the results that my query shows in the SQL, and i«m not sure why I would like someone to help me find the problem, I have the following code below:
My query in php (it shows 2 results in SQL of 2 different cards from the same person, but in php it just shows one result)

```
$sql='SELECT Card.*
FROM Card
WHERE ValidUntil <= Cast(DateAdd( DD ,7 , GetDate() ) as Date)
ORDER BY ValidUntil ASC';
$stm = $conn->query($sql);
```

My cycle in php after my query:

> > **OLD CODE**
> >
> > ```
> > if (!$stm)
> > {
> >     echo "";
> > }
> > else
> > {
> >     while ($rows2 = $stm->fetch())
> >     {
> >     $CType = isset($rows2['CardType']) ? $rows2['CardType'] : NULL;
> >     $CNr = isset($rows2['CardNr']) ? $rows2['CardNr'] : NULL;
> >     $CValFrom = isset($rows2['ValidFrom']) ? $rows2['ValidFrom'] : NULL;
> >     $CValUntil = isset($rows2['ValidUntil']) ? $rows2['ValidUntil'] : NULL;
> >     $CLTCCTime = isset($rows2['LastTccTime']) ? $rows2['LastTccTime'] : NULL;
> >     echo
> > ```
>
> '
>
> ';
>
> > ```
> >     $tableHeaders = [
> >     ['variable' => 'CType', 'title' => 'Tipo'],
> >     ['variable' => 'CNr', 'title' => 'Nr.'],
> >     ['variable' => 'CValFrom', 'title' => 'Válido Desde'],
> >     ['variable' => 'CValUntil', 'title' => 'Válido Até'],
> >     ['variable' => 'CLTCCTime', 'title' => 'Dia/Hora no Último Terminal'],
> >     ];
> >
> >     foreach($tableHeaders as $tableHeader):
> >         $variable = $tableHeader['variable'];
> >         if (isset($$variable) AND !is_null($$variable) AND !empty(trim($$variable))):
> >             echo '<th>' . $tableHeader['title'] . '</th>';
> >         endif;
> >     endforeach;
> >
> >     echo '</tr></thead>';
> > echo '<tbody><tr>';
> >
> >         $tableDatas1 = [
> >         ['variable1' => 'CType', 'data1' => $CType],
> >         ['variable1' => 'CNr', 'data1' => $CNr],
> >         ['variable1' => 'CValFrom', 'data1' => $mytime1],
> >         ['variable1' => 'CValUntil', 'data1' => $mytime2],
> >         ['variable1' => 'CLTCCTime', 'data1' => $mytime3],
> >         ];
> >
> >         foreach($tableDatas1 as $tableData1):
> >             $variable1 = $tableData1['variable1'];
> >             if (isset($$variable1) AND !is_null($$variable1) AND !empty(trim($$variable1))):
> >
> >                 echo '<td class="text_body">' . $tableData1['data1'] . '</td>';
> >             endif;
> >         endforeach;
> >
> >         echo '</tr></br>';
> >     }
> > }
> > echo '</tbody></table></body>';
> > ```

After reading the comments I started changing my code, and at some point it shows all the results that it should, but it was showing for each row one `tableheader` and I only want a single one, and the results below it, I have made the following changes, but now it still appears **only one result again**

```
if (!$stm)
{
    echo "";
}
else
{
    $rowsCabecalho = $stm->fetch();
    $CType = isset($rowsCabecalho['CardType']) ? $rowsCabecalho['CardType'] : NULL;
    $CNr = isset($rowsCabecalho['CardNr']) ? $rowsCabecalho['CardNr'] : NULL;
    $CValFrom = isset($rowsCabecalho['ValidFrom']) ? $rowsCabecalho['ValidFrom'] : NULL;
    $CValUntil = isset($rowsCabecalho['ValidUntil']) ? $rowsCabecalho['ValidUntil'] : NULL;
    $CLTCCTime = isset($rowsCabecalho['LastTccTime']) ? $rowsCabecalho['LastTccTime'] : NULL;
        $CCodingDate = isset($rowsCabecalho['CodingDate']) ? $rowsCabecalho['CodingDate'] : NULL;
    echo '<div class="informaltable"><p></p><table cellspacing="2" border="0"><thead><tr>';
    $tableHeaders = [
    ['variable' => 'CType', 'title' => 'Tipo'],
    ['variable' => 'CNr', 'title' => 'Nr.'],
    ['variable' => 'CValFrom', 'title' => 'Válido Desde'],
    ['variable' => 'CValUntil', 'title' => 'Válido Até'],
    ['variable' => 'CLTCCTime', 'title' => 'Dia/Hora no Último Terminal'],
    ];
    foreach($tableHeaders as $tableHeader):
        $variable = $tableHeader['variable'];
        if (isset($$variable) AND !is_null($$variable) AND !empty(trim($$variable))):
            echo '<th>' . $tableHeader['title'] . '</th>';
        endif;
    endforeach;
    echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';
}

if (!$stm)
{
    echo "";
}
else
{
    while ($rows2 = $stm->fetch())
    {
        $CType = isset($rows2['CardType']) ? $rows2['CardType'] : NULL;
        $CNr = isset($rows2['CardNr']) ? $rows2['CardNr'] : NULL;
        $CValFrom = isset($rows2['ValidFrom']) ? $rows2['ValidFrom'] : NULL;
        $CValUntil = isset($rows2['ValidUntil']) ? $rows2['ValidUntil'] : NULL;
        $CLTCCTime = isset($rows2['LastTccTime']) ? $rows2['LastTccTime'] : NULL;
        $CCodingDate = isset($rows2['CodingDate']) ? $rows2['CodingDate'] : NULL;

        echo '<tr>';
        $tableDatas1 = [
        ['variable1' => 'CType', 'data1' => $CType],
        ['variable1' => 'CNr', 'data1' => $CNr],
        ['variable1' => 'CValFrom', 'data1' => $mytime1],
        ['variable1' => 'CValUntil', 'data1' => $mytime2],
        ['variable1' => 'CLTCCTime', 'data1' => $mytime3],
        ];
        foreach($tableDatas1 as $tableData1):
            $variable1 = $tableData1['variable1'];
            if (isset($$variable1) AND !is_null($$variable1) AND !empty(trim($$variable1))):
                echo '<td class="text_body">' . $tableData1['data1'] . '</td>';
            endif;
        endforeach;
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
echo '</tbody></table></body>';
```

Comment: I think the fetch statement is fault. You need to fetch_assoc(). Try   $row = fetch_assoc($stm).

Comment: You've made a change in your code. Is this last version of you code? Thanks.

Comment: @Zhorov I've made some changes now, with your answer below it was working, showing all the results, but it was not the way I wanted because I had one header for each row, I«ve made some changes as you can see in the updated, but now I still only get one row

Comment: @AnoushkaIola OK, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Remove `$rowsCabecalho = $stm->fetch();` from your code. First, you never use `$rowsCabecalho` and second, don't call `$stm->fetch()` twice.

Use [PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) like this:

```
<?php
...
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
   foreach($row => $value) {
      echo $value;
   }
   // your code ...
}
...

?>
```

**Update:**

If you want to print the header, and then the rows, you may try with this:

```
<?php
echo '<div class="informaltable"><p></p><table cellspacing="2" border="0"><thead><tr>';
$tableHeaders = [
['variable' => 'CType', 'title' => 'Tipo'],
['variable' => 'CNr', 'title' => 'Nr.'],
['variable' => 'CValFrom', 'title' => 'Válido Desde'],
['variable' => 'CValUntil', 'title' => 'Válido Até'],
['variable' => 'CLTCCTime', 'title' => 'Dia/Hora no Último Terminal'],
];
foreach($tableHeaders as $tableHeader):
    $variable = $tableHeader['variable'];
    echo '<th>' . $tableHeader['title'] . '</th>';
endforeach;
echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';

if (!$stm)
{
    echo "";
}
else
{
    while ($rows2 = $stm->fetch())
    {
        $CType = isset($rows2['CardType']) ? $rows2['CardType'] : NULL;
        $CNr = isset($rows2['CardNr']) ? $rows2['CardNr'] : NULL;
        $CValFrom = isset($rows2['ValidFrom']) ? $rows2['ValidFrom'] : NULL;
        $CValUntil = isset($rows2['ValidUntil']) ? $rows2['ValidUntil'] : NULL;
        $CLTCCTime = isset($rows2['LastTccTime']) ? $rows2['LastTccTime'] : NULL;
        $CCodingDate = isset($rows2['CodingDate']) ? $rows2['CodingDate'] : NULL;

        echo '<tr>';
        $tableDatas1 = [
        ['variable1' => 'CType', 'data1' => $CType],
        ['variable1' => 'CNr', 'data1' => $CNr],
        ['variable1' => 'CValFrom', 'data1' => $mytime1],
        ['variable1' => 'CValUntil', 'data1' => $mytime2],
        ['variable1' => 'CLTCCTime', 'data1' => $mytime3],
        ];
        foreach($tableDatas1 as $tableData1):
            $variable1 = $tableData1['variable1'];
            if (isset($$variable1) AND !is_null($$variable1) AND !empty(trim($$variable1))):
                echo '<td class="text_body">' . $tableData1['data1'] . '</td>';
            endif;
        endforeach;
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
echo '</tbody></table></body>';
?>
```

Comment: It's working and the code is smaller than it was! I really thought I would have to use all those fetch and ifs.
THanks!